# Registry image is not stored in Storage in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `session()` to create several form pages, but I'm having a problem related to the field `avatar_hunter` because it's not stored inside `storage/app/{id_record}` the file, inside `submitFormulario()` has the condition that verifies its existence and stores the image of the record. How do I resolve this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\HunterModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class HunterController extends Controller
{

    public function begin()
    {
        return view('page1');
    }

    public function pageForm1(Request $request)
    {

        $validacoes = $request->validate([
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'avatar_hunter' => 'required',
            'age_hunter' => 'required|integer|min:13',
        ]);

        session()->put('page', $validations);

        return view('page2');
    }

    public function pageForm2(Hunter2Request $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();

        session()->put('page2', $validations);

        return view('page3');
    }

    public function pageForm3(Hunter3Request $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();

        session()->put('page3', $validations);

        return redirect()->route('submitForm');
    }

    public function submitForm(Request $request)
    {
     
        $page1 = session()->get('page1');
        $page2 = session()->get('page2');
        $page3 = session()->get('page3');

        $hunter = HunterModel::create(array_merge($page1, $page2, $page3));

        if ($request->hasFile('avatar_hunter')) {

            $avatar = $request->file('avatar_hunter');

            $avatar_name = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $avatar_path = $avatar->storeAs('avatars/' . $hunter->id, $avatar_name, 'public');

            $hunter->avatar_hunter = $avatar_path;
            $hunter->save();
        }

        session()->forget(['page1', 'page2', 'page3']);

        return redirect()->route('begin');
    }

}
```